# Chef InSpec test for testing a path presence in %PATH%

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, inspec

I want to check whether a path has been added in windows **%PATH%** environment variable, using InSpec test in Chef. I'm not able to find any hints online.

```
describe command('echo %PATH%') do
  its('stdout') { should match /C:\SoftwareX\bin/ }
end
```

It's not working. Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`echo` is not a program, it's a `cmd.exe` built-in. Try `command('cmd.exe /c "echo %PATH%"')` or similar. You could also use a copy of `env` built for windows if you have one on the machine already.

Comment: Thanks for replying! I tried 'echo 'hello'' and it does work. The problem is %PATH% is taken as a string, and not a env var. I will try your suggestion.

Comment: For the sake of posterity, using 'os_env' is better choice.